# using variable n regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

```
         var d = new Date();
        string[] weekday = new string[10];
        weekday[0] = "Söndag";
        weekday[1] = "Måndag";
        weekday[2] = "Tisdag";
        weekday[3] = "Onsdag";
        weekday[4] = "Torsdag";
        weekday[5] = "Fredag";
        weekday[6] = "Lördag";
        int day = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        var n = weekday[day];

        var match = Regex.Match(item.InnerText, @"\b" + n + "\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);

        Response.Write(match.Value);
```

i get the "unrecognized escape sequence" error on \s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*) when i put in the variable. It works fine when it's only @"\bMåndag\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);

Comment: `...+ @"\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)"`, please add `@` since `\s` is actually an unknown symbol

Comment: It is not even related to a variable.

Comment: We have **7** days in the week, why you've declared `10`? in the `string[] weekday = new string[10];`? Change it into `string[] weekday = new string[] {"Söndag", "Måndag", ... , "Lördag"};`

Comment: The `@` works for the string literal it's attached to, not for the entire string that will eventually be built. So you need to repeat the `@` for the second literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use @ for regex

```
var match = Regex.Match(item.InnerText, @"\b" + n + @"\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```